# Quantidade minima jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Preciso de um código jquery que ao clicar no submit ele apareça um alerta e não deixe o usuario continuar a menos que tenha digitado 10 caracteres dentro do input

```html
<form action="add.php" id = "form" method="post">
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Descricao">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="actions" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Além da verificação com método `.length`, é importante tratar de espaços vazios, caso contrário, se forem inseridos 10 x <kbd>space</kbd> no campo, o `if($('#Descricao').val().length < 10)` vai retornar *true* (vai validar) porque o <kbd>space</kbd> também é computado como um caractere.

Também não é interessante que se tenha espaços vazios nas extremidades do valor, pelo mesmo motivo citado acima.

Para tratar (eliminar) esses espaços *indesejados*, pode-se usar o método **[.trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ff679971(v=vs.94).aspx)**, que elimina os espaços antes e depois da string:

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function() {
   if($('#Descricao').val().trim().length < 10) {
      alert('Tem menos de 10 chars');
      return false;
   }
   return true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="Descricao" />
    <input type="submit" value="Verificar" />
</form>
```

Comment: boa garoto isso ai

Answer (score 4):

Quando todos os navegadores tiverem suporte, será possível utilizar o atributo `min-length` no HTML. Você pode acompanhar por [este link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-minlength) quais navegadores já contam com esse recurso atualmente.

Ainda assim, você não precisa fazer uso de JQuery para resolver esse problema. Pode-se utilizar em conjunto os atributos [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-required) e [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern) do HTML5. Definindo o *pattern* como `.{10,}` você faz com que o formulário seja submetido somente quando o usuário inserir 10 ou mais caracteres:

```html
<form action="add.php" id = "form" method="post">
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Descricao" pattern=".{10,}" title='Insira 10 ou mais caracteres.' required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="actions" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### [youmightnotneedjquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: O "min-length" será uma ótima solução front-end para esse tipo de problema.
Obrigado pela ajua, mais precisava de uma solução via código.
Resolvido.

Answer (score 1):

Eis um código funcional com seu exemplo solicitado:

```js
$(function() {
 
  $('#enviar').click(function () {
  var desc = $('#Descricao').val();
      
      if(desc.length <= 9){
        alert('são no minimo 10 caracteres');
      }else{
        $('#form').submit();
      }
 });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="add.php" id="form" method="post">
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Descricao">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="actions" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Foi colocado id no seu button, e alterado o tipo. Usando jquery eu peguei o valor do campo descrição:

```
var desc = $('#Descricao').val();
```

e verifiquei se ele era no tamanho, se for o form da submit()

```
if(desc.length <= 9){
    alert('são no minimo 10 caracteres');
}else{
   $('#form').submit();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda !!!

Answer (score 0):

Alguém tinha postado a resposta para o meu problema, mais não sei por qual motivo apagou o post.
A resposta era essa:

```html
$('#form').on('submit', function() {
if($('#Descricao').val().length < 10) {
  alert('Tem menos de 10 chars');
  return false;
}
return true;
  });
```

Comment: É interessante tratar também de espaços vazios. Se o cara digitar 10 espaços vazios no input, esse código vai validar considerando que existem 10 caracteres no campo, já que o espaço tb é um caractere

Comment: realmente é uma boa idéia. No meu caso não será necessário, mais se fosse um projeto profissional com certeza seria

Comment: Realmente, se for só um projeto onde não haja essa preocupação, não seria necessário. Porém eu vou postar uma resposta para enriquecer mais o post e que possa ajudar a outros. Abs!

Comment: Ok.. Quanto mais gente for ajudada melhor